# Spring Boot: wrong configuration order since upgrade to 1.3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've upgraded my application from 1.2.7 (and spring 4.2.2) to 1.3.0 (with 4.2.3).

Now I've seen that some of my externalized configurations are not working as expected.

For example I've a property value `my.property=aaa` which is defined in my `application.yml` (included in my jar-file under classpath root).

Now, if I start my app from command line, I use a externalized config file like this:

```
java -jar my-app.jar --spring.config.location=file:/mytest.properties
```

which includes and overwrites the `my.property=bbb`. In Spring Boot 1.2.7 the result is `bbb` - as expected. But in 1.3.0 I got `my.property=aaa`!?

If I call the `GET:/env` endpoint I got a changed ordering of configurations.
in 1.2.7 I got *):

```
...
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-test.yml]": {...},
"applicationConfig: [file:/mytest.properties]": {...},
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]": {...}
...
```

*) *which is also not what I've expected since the `file:/` should be the first. Thus it seems to me that the ordering in in JSON response is not exactly the same as for springs property resolver mechanism.*

in 1.3.0 instead it is:

```
...
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#default": {...},
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-test.yml]": {...},
"applicationConfig: [file:/mytest.properties]": {...}
...
```

Did I miss a thing in change log? Is there a further property to set to got the previous ordering back?

---

**Edited:**

After enabling a few spring debug-loggings I've found out that it seems to be no specific 1.3.0 issue - moreover the cases where my configuration works (even with 1.2.7) are only lucky coincidences... The ordering changes on every restart. One time I got a configuration as I expect. The second time it is completely different. No changes in code or my start script - just stop/start my application...

I see this in my logs:

**in 1.2.7 (relevant is the last line in this log - this is exactly what I expect):**

```
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [commandLineArgs] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [random] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-pretest.yml]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [file:/xxx/service/xxx/properties/xxx_pretest.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [commandLineArgs]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [servletContextInitParams]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [systemProperties]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [systemEnvironment]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [random]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-pretest.yml]]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [applicationConfig: [file:/xxx/service/xxx/properties/xxx_pretest.properties]]
2015-11-18 19:17:39,141 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [applicationConfig: [file:/xxx/service/xxx/properties/xxx_pretest.properties]] with type [String] and value
'https://xxx:1111/services/EntitlementService'
```

**in 1.3.0 (most interesting is the last line in this log - unexpected result):**

```
2015-11-18 19:34:40,608 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [environmentProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:40,608 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:40,632 DEBUG core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:40,632 DEBUG core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:40,633 DEBUG core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2015-11-18 19:34:41,044 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [commandLineArgs] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,044 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,044 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [random] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#default] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-pretest.yml]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [file:/xxx/service/xxx/properties/xxx_pretest.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,045 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [commandLineArgs] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [random] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#default] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-pretest.yml]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [file:/xxx/service/xxx/properties/xxx_pretest.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-11-18 19:34:41,046 DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
...
2015-11-18 19:34:42,811 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [environmentProperties]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [commandLineArgs]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [servletContextInitParams]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [systemProperties]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [systemEnvironment]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [random]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#default]
2015-11-18 19:34:42,812 DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#default] with type [String] and value 'https://localhost:9448/service
s/EntitlementService'
```

Unfortunately, after enabling the spring 'core.env' loggings the whole property resolving mechanism looks quite suspect to me. I see a huge amount of `DEBUG core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [...] PropertySource with lowest search precedence` outputs mingled with `DEBUG core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'xxx.entitlement.endpoint.url' in [...]`. I would expect only one block with `Adding [...]` and **after that** the `Searching for key ...` blocks. But not mixed together. But the thing I wonder is why my external configuration file gets the lowest priority instead of the highest!?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in the following way after migration to 1.3.0.RELEASE:

- Create runnable jar with bundled `application.properties` containing one configuration key:

  server.context-path=/default
- Create another `application.properties` in `/tmp` with overridden config property:

  server.context-path=/override
- Run the jar: `java -jar -Dspring.config.location=/tmp/application.properties my-application.jar`

Application is now available at `http://localhost:8080/override/`.

In this experiment results are consistent with 1.2.7.RELEASE.

Comment: hmm... thank you for your answer. thus it seems to me I'm forced to create a test-application which reproduces my issue (or not).